# Tornado: Create full URL from partial URL

Tags: python, url, tornado

I was wondering if there's a function or... something in Tornado that would turn a partial URL into a complete URI.

Let's say I have a CSS file in `/static/css/thingy.css` and my the server is reachable via HTTPS on `192.168.1.4:8000`. Is there a function that would do:

```
function_something("/static/css/thingy.css")
```

returns: `"https://192.168.1.4:8000/static/css/thingy.css"`

The issue seems to be pretty easily solvable (I'm guessing) but, for one, I'm a beginner to Tornado and also, I haven't been able to find a reply in Google.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I found something that is not as straight forward as I wanted, but having access to a [Tornado HTTPRequest](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.2/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest), you can get information about the `protocol`, `host`... So I can do:

```
url = ("%s://%s/static/css/thingy.css" %
          (self.request.protocol,
          self.request.host,)
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a python file then a simple + will do the job for you. Concatenating  strings in python is done like this:

```
string1 + string2
```

so for you it would be

```
"https://192.168.1.4:8000" + "/static/css/thingy.css"
```

but of course you have these two strings in variables, lets say they are called host and place so it would be

```
 url = host + place
```

and then the url variable would contain your full path.

Comment: Well... I was expecting a more automated way. Something like... [the Django build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

Comment: You can also use urljoin from the urlparse module (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin), but this is all standard python.